# Highcharts - How can I fit a chart's long title for printing

Tags: highcharts

The graph below appears on a website and has a very long title. The graph needs to be printed, using the Highcharts print menu, but as you can see the title of the graph (which has to be that one) does not fit in the page. Is there a way I can fit long titles of graphs for printing? Thank you for your help.
[image]

Comment: Which version of Highcarts are you using? With the latest there are no problems with long titles. See here : [http://jsfiddle.net/8Lzvushv/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lzvushv/1/) and try to print.

Comment: The title of your chart is set by the property `title : { text : .... }` ?

Comment: Please provide the configuration options of your chart.

Comment: Actually you were right the property was not correct. We fixed it. Thanks!